Hono.js Vercel runtime have problems with bcrypt.js and bcrypt
Normally we can't use bcrypt in edge functions.
So when using bcrypt.js
    const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
    const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(password, salt);

This produces an error
    TypeError: import_bcryptjs.default.genSalt is not a function]

This error throws for everything (hash, hashsync, gensalt, gensaltsync)
I expected this to work normally but as I mentioned above it throws an error
    TypeError: import_bcryptjs.default.genSalt is not a function]

I have installed
    bun i @types/bcryptjs

and
    bun i bcryptjs

so I don't know what's the problem and it's not a typo error.
So Then I tried @fntools/password a npm package which works well.
@fntools/password npm package
well then is there something I'm missing in bcrypt.js?
my tsconfig.js -->
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
  },
}

my vercel.json -->
{
  "rewrites": [
    {
      "source": "/api/(.*)",
      "destination": "/api"
    }
  ]
}

working code -->
import PasswordHasher from "@fntools/password";
const encrypt = new PasswordHasher(10);

export const HashPass = (password: string) => {
    const hashedPassword = encrypt.hash(password);
    console.log(hashedPassword);
    return hashedPassword;
};


I have the same problem. Do you have a solution to this problem?
